# Angular 2 service initialization logic

Tags: angular

I have angular 2 service called `JwtService.ts` used to check for **JWT token** and use it in my different components in order to know if the user is a guest or logged in member.

I get the token fine from my `LocalStorage` every time the service starts, but for some reasons it's looking for it 3 times (every time a component using the service) and I'm pretty sure it has to be retrived only once for all components.

Look at the following code of my `JwtService.ts:`

```
export class JwtService {

    private jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    public myData = this.getUserData();

    constructor(public router: Router,private http: Http) {
    }

    getToken() {
        return this.jwtToken;
    }

    setToken(theToken)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('jwt', theToken);
        this.jwtToken = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    }

    logOut()
    {
            this.jwtToken = null;
            localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
            this.router.navigate( ['Home'] );
    }

    getUserData()
    {
    console.log("Getting user..");
    this.http.get('http://localhost/PokemonAPI/public/api/v1/thisUser?token='+this.getToken())
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => {this.myData = data.user;
        console.log()
        },
        err => {
            this.JwtService.checkToken(err);
            console.error(err); },
        () => console.log("User logged!");
      );
    }

    getUser()
    {
        return this.myData;
    }
}
```

Yes, it works, but if I check my browser console I see this:

[image: Console]

which means the browser loaded the service 3 times and used my HTTP GET 3 times in one run.
Why is that and what can cause this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume this is because you added

```
providers: [JwtService]
```

on 3 different components.

Add it only on the root component (AppComponent) or alternatively in `bootstrap(AppComponent, [JwtService]);`

For each component where you add it a new instance is maintained by DI.

Comment: Thank you master of Angular 2!